# match datetime pattern with spring DatetimeFormat annotation

Tags: spring-mvc, jquery-inputmask

I'm trying to use this jquery input mask plugin to submit a date time field.

The input is being submitted as:

`081220151530` - which is 3:30pm 08/12/2015

or in am/pm it's submitting
`081220150330p`

I'm trying to bind that value to a Joda DateTime field and I think I should be able to specify a custom pattern on the field annotation.

But this pattern's not matching and throwing a validation fault:

```
@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat(pattern = "DDMMYYYYhhmm")
private DateTime followUp;
```

The error:

```
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.joda.time.DateTime' for property 'followUp'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @javax.persistence.Basic @org.hibernate.annotations.Type @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat org.joda.time.DateTime for value '081220151230'; nested exception is org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException: Cannot parse "081220151230": Value 22 for monthOfYear must be in the range [1,12]
```

So 2 questions:
1. Ideally, it could parse the am/pm value, so is there a pattern that will match the am/pm style?

2. If not, what's the right pattern string to match the 24 hour version?

---

**Update to original question:**

So I figured out the 24H pattern, using the DateFormat pattern `ddMMyyyyHHmm`

But the second part I can't get - so I'm going to reassign this to the `jquery-inputmask` tag because the fact that it's submitting the am/pm as `a` and `p` respectively maybe a bug....

So I think I can solve this if someone knows how to make it submit pm/am instead?

Answer (score 0):

try: ddMMyyyyHHmma
post the value like 05052016

Comment: post the value like 050520161234PM